# How can we save special symbols in xml

Tags: c#, xml, character-encoding

I am saving "Childrenâ€™s Music & videos" to xml

so i used the following code to convert the special symbols

```
        string str = "Childrenâ€™s Music & videos";
        string temp = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(str);
```

but the xml is not readable after saving the encoded value. How can i save this special symbols to xml

Thanks,

Comment: What is you xml header? I just want to check the text encoding. Its possible that your text encoding might not support some chars.

Comment: Why do you do _HTML_ encoding if you work with XML?

Comment: I'd say s?he doesn't know any better. For people not familiar with the intricacies of XML they do appear very similar.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the right text in the string to start with, using the normal XML APIs should encode everything properly for you.

My guess is that you have bad text in your strings. See my [Debugging Unicode Problems](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/debuggingunicode.html) article for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to save the special character as its numerical `&<nnnn>;` representation.

Please see Wikipedia for more - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: You can embed arbitrary text just fine without escaping (unless it's `<` or `'`), you just need to take care of your charsets (or just use XML APIs that will automagically do The Right Thing™ for you :-))

Comment: ok - I've always relied on making sure it Does The Right Thing by forcing the encoding :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the the tag `<![CDATA[ ]]>` to wrap around text with special characters.

Here's more on [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp).